# memset clone producing weird results

Tags: c

I'm trying to copy the memset function. For a reason I don't understand, the following code does not work and produces weird results:

```
#include <sys/types.h>

void    *mem_set(void *dst, int c, size_t n)
{
    char    *d;
    size_t  i;

    d = dst;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        d[i] = (unsigned char) c;
    return dst;
}
```

Here's the test:

```
int     *a;
a = malloc(4 * sizeof(int));
a[0] = 1;
a[1] = 2;
a[2] = 3;
a[3] = 4;
printf("%d %d %d %d\n", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);
mem_set(a, 1, 4);
printf("%d %d %d %d\n", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);
free(a);
```

And here the output:

```
1 2 3 4
16843009 2 3 4
```

Comment: `sizeof (int) != sizeof (char)`

Comment: The problem is that your array `a` is an array of `int` but your `mem_set` is assuming bytes (chars). Try `char *a;` and `malloc(4 * sizeof(char));`

Comment: Before asking "What's wrong with my `memset` implementation", perhaps you first should compare the results of your implementation against the results of the normal `memset`.

Comment: Looks right to me... As noted elsewhere, `16843009 == 0x01010101`, and `sizeof(int)` appears to be 4 on your system (and perhaps more importantly, is not equal to `sizeof(char)`).

Comment: Kudos for including a small self-contained program and the obtained results, but you should have included expected results too (since it appears at first sight this is where the bug is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `memset` is fine. It's just that you're not using it correctly (or not understanding what it's meant to do when applied to an array of `int`).

To fill the entire array, the

```
mem_set(a, 1, 4);
```

should read

```
mem_set(a, 1, 4 * sizeof(int));
```

The output should then become `16843009 16843009 16843009 16843009` (i.e. `0x01010101` repeated four times [1]). If you are expecting the output to be `1 1 1 1`, then `memset` is not the right tool for the job.

[1] Assuming, for the sake of argument, that `sizeof(int)==4`.

Comment: Or: `mem_set(a, 1, 4 * sizeof *a);`